# Setting the background of an activity to a custom livewallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, android-theme

It's possible to set the background of an activity to show a livewallpaper by using or extending @android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.

However using that theme will only show you the current livewallpaper that the user has chosen, is it possible to specify which livewallpaper we want to show in the background?